# Asymptotic expansion of cosine/sine integral

Tags: asymptotics, bessel-functions, trigonometric-integrals

For $a,b$ in some compact interval $I$, consider the integral function $K_{a,b}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$ defined by

$$K_{a,b}(x)=\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{\pi} \cos(ax\cos(t))\sin(bx\sin(t)) \, dt \quad (x\in\mathbb{R}).$$

Has anybody an idea about an asymptotic expansion of this integral for $x\rightarrow\infty$ (for fixed $a,b$)? Is it perhaps even possible to have some kind of an uniform estimate, i.e.
$$\vert K_{a,b}(x)\vert\leq K(x)$$
for all $a,b\in I, x\in\mathbb{R}$ and some function $K:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $K(x)\rightarrow 0 \ (x\rightarrow\infty)$ of which we know an asymptotic expansion?

Comment: i think this integral can be related to Besselfunction for which asymptotics and bounds are easy to look up

Answer (score 1):

Three parameters are unecessary. You can let $ax\to x$ and $bx\to y$ to reduce to
$$F(x,y)=\int_0^\pi \cos(x\cos t)\sin(y\sin t)\mathrm dt$$
Let $f(x,y,t)=\cos(x\cos t)\sin(y \sin t)$. The key observation is that $f$ satisfies the PDE (check this)
$$\partial_x^2 f+\partial_y^2 f+f=0$$
And, by the Leibniz rule, $F$ satisfies this PDE as well, as well as having the boundary condition
$$F(x,0)=0$$

Separation of variables should do the trick here. Unfortunately I don't have the time right now to go through this myself.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. One should also have the boundary condition $F(0,y)=\pi H_{0}(y)$ where $H_{0}$ is the Struve function of order $0.$ Therefore, we should have the boundary problem $$\Delta f+f=0, f(x,0)=0, f(0,y)=\pi H_{0}(y).$$ The PDE is the Helmholtz equation and I have tried a separation of variables but unfortunately I came to a point where I run out of information. Are the boundary conditions enough to determine an exact solution of this problem? And is this solution unique? If so, how can one prove this?